# Подскажите с архитектурой «подключаемых модулей»

Tags: php

*Привет, сразу скажу что пишу (CMS) велосипед, для себя, поэтому ответы в стиле: используй Joomla (Wordpress, ModX) не приму. Кто хочет немного порассуждать, Welcome:*

Есть идея сделать независимые подключаемые модули управления к своей системе, т.е. существует некая папка `sub/` куда будут складываться эти модули (файлы php) и инклюдиться по мере необходимости. Так собственно вопрос:

Нужно автоматически составлять список этих модулей (читай: список файлов, `scandir`) но НЕ выполнять код (`include`), а только собрать определенные данные из них (читай: массив $this_mod).

Для ясности:

```
get_submodules_list.php

<?php
$sub_dir = 'sys/sub/';
$sub_mods = scandir($sub_dir);

array_splice($sub_mods, 0, 2); // отрезаем . и .. вначале массива

foreach ($sub_mods as $val) { 
    echo '<a href="' . $sub_dir . $val . '">' . $val . '</a>'; // выводим ссылки
}
?>
```

.
    _submodule_pattern.php

```
<?php

$this_mod['name'] = 'Контент';
$this_mod['version'] = '1.0.0';
$this_mod['parametr0'] = true;
$this_mod['parametr1'] = false;
$this_mod['parametrN'] = null;

/*
    some code
*/

?>
```

Придумал открывать построчно и парсить регуляркой массив, но мне кажется это ужасный бред.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А откуда такой страх include? Например, в моем "велосипеде" аналогичные модули состоят из нескольких файлов, один из которых - файл конфигурации модуля. Соответственно, файлы конфигурации подключаются всегда, а остальные файлы модуля - по мере надобности. Ну а за счет общих принципов именования файлов, для подключения всех конфигов модулей используется функция `glob()` - но этот момент уже на любителя.

Comment: Да, "сделать конфиг" для модуля был запасным вариантом, для меня.

НО: очень бы хотелось уместить всё в один файл, как вы считаете,
парсить регуляркой данные, скажем из комментов типа:

    <?php
    // mod_name = 'Content'
    // mod_paramX = 'Some data'
    echo 'some php data';
    ?>

слишком «коряво»? или ещё придумал вообще такую ерундну как две, переменные переменные одна массив конфигов, а вторую тупо eval при надобности, но это наверно совсем :)


Comment: Любая работа с регулярными выражениями - сама по себе очень ресурсоемкая операция. Да и файлы для чтения все равно придется грузить. А на счет "уместить в один файл"... Зачем? Уместите в одном каталоге. Модулю может и js-часть потребоваться, и шаблоны какие-нибудь - все равно одним файлом в перспективе отделаться не получится.

Comment: Про js, и шаблоны - не подумал, убедили более чем, благодарю Вас!